# How can I map ANYDATA oracle type into Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class ("ParameterValue.java") with a variable called "value" which can be of different types (String, Integer, Float, Date).

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VALUE_PARAMETERS)
public class ParameterValue implements Serializable {

    private Long id;    
    private Object value;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_PARAMETERS", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_PARAMETERS", sequenceName = "SEQ_PARAMETERS", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "ID_PARAMETER_VALUE")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name="VALUE")
public Object getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

I discovered the type [ANYDATA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ANYDATA.html) in Oracle but I'm not able to get it working and don't found any mention in Hibernate documentation.  How can I tell Hibernate to map this ANYDATA column into that variable?

As an alternative I can define several columns, one per type, but I would prefer to use a single column.